# How to export an output in a special cell in an excel file?

Tags: export, excel

My general question is: How can I put each of my outputs (a number) in a special cell of a given sheet of an excel file? for example I have built an excel file (say results.xlsx) and I want to fill it by my outputs (say `out[i]`s). For example I want to put `out[1]` in B5 cell of first sheet of results.xls, `out[2]` in C10 cell of second sheet of results.xls and etc. How can this be done?

We can simplify the above problem: suppose I have built a table (say outs) using my outputs and export it  as an excel file () as follows

```
out[1] = 1;
out[2] = 2;
out[3] = 3;
out[4] = 4;

outs1=Table[out[i], {i, 1, 4}];
Export["results.xlsx", outs1, "Data"]
```

this command gives me an excel file which has a row including values of out1.

I run another .nb file and do the same namely I build another table (outs2) as follows

```
out[5] = 5;
out[6] = 6;
out[7] = 7;
out[8] = 8;

outs2=Table[out[i], {i, 5, 8}];
```

Now I want to put outs2 as second row of results.xlsx file. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way is making a sparse array and putting there the result at the desired place.

```
s = SparseArray[{{11, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 13} -> 
     4}, {12, 15}, ""];
s // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Than you can export it to Excel

Comment: Thanks a lot this was a useful way. In fact it was answer of my general question. But what about my second one? namely if I want to construct an excel file using different .nb files where outputs of each file make a row of an excel file?

Comment: @Wisdom, you should compose an output array containing all the data at the desired places before exporting. The easiest way for this is making sparse array from one data-set and further correction of elements by something like `s[[3;;5,4;;7]]=subarray`

Comment: Many thanks. Do you mean there is no way to fill my excel file gradually and by running each .nb file (as I explained above)? I think there should be a way, because it doesn't seem a hard work

Comment: @Wisdom, of course, you can do it gradually. All the evaluated data of a Mathematica session are stored in the kernel. You can run step-by-step any cells from the different notebooks to make the inclusions of subarrays into the output array that was created at the beginning as sparse.

Comment: Thanks I got it, however your suggestion has an additional intermediate step (constructing one data-set) but my mean was an one-step command in the each nb file.

Comment: @Wisdom, this intermediate step can be done in one click - just as command that inserts all the needed data into the resulting array.